# Navigation bar and pull-down menu eerily brighter

Tags: user-interface

Occasionally, my phone's display goes significantly dark. However, the navbar and the pull-down notifications menu are very brightly lit up. Any idea why?

[image: weirdly lit navbar]

I'm running Android 10 on Samsung M30.

P.S. Sorry about the terrible quality.

P.P.S This is not some setting, as it happens and disappears on its own. I'm trying to trace what stimulates such an eerie UI get-up.

Comment: As it currently stands, this might be a question for our photography sister side on "how to get the glare out of a reflecting object" ;) As @Robert already stated: hard to tell what you're asking.

Comment: I could see that the navigation bar is lit, but not sure where/what the pull-down menu is (Notification panel? App launcher?). However, did this happen recently/suddenly? I don't have a Samsung device, but I'd guess there's a setting inside Display about ambient light for navigation bar or similar thing?